# Why is it so important to redefine Function.prototype before instantiation of any objects?

Tags: javascript, prototype

From [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#With_a_constructor)

```
function Graph() {
  this.vertices = [];
  this.edges = [];
}

Graph.prototype = {
  addVertex: function(v){
    this.vertices.push(v);
  }
};

var g = new Graph();
```

If I first redefine prototype, and then create an object using constructor functio (like in the example), everything works (i.e. I can call `g.addVertex("a");`). But if i swap `Graph.prototype = {...}` and `var g = new Graph();` - I can't call `g.addVertex()` function (method) anymore. Why?

Comment: If you want to really understand Javascript prototypes, I'd highly recommend checking this out: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch5.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally it's fine to change the protoype of existing objects' constructor. However, you're assigning a whole new object to Graph.prototype, so the reference that the instance had in its `__proto__` property is no longer
the same as Graph.prototype.

If instead you add the method to the existing prototype, like this:

```
Graph.prototype.addVertex = function(v){
    this.vertices.push(v)
}
```

Then it'll work in any order.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are redefining the entire prototype after the instance is created, meaning that all new instances will get the new prototype, but already created instances won't. An instance won't know that the prototype of the constructor function where it came from has completely changed.

Comment: Thank you! I thought old instances would still have access to the new prototype's method and properties. Can't choose two answers as the ones that solved my problem! But thank you again!

Comment: They will have access as long as you don't completely redefine the prototype, if you add a method/property to the existing one they will get it.